# cart.phtml override issue

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, overrides

I am trying to override `cart.phtml` from `checkout\cart.phtml`  using `local.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>test/cart.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

override works fine but when i try to empty cart it always call my `cart.phtml` instead of `checkout\cart\noItems.phtml`.

when my cart is empty then it looks like

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods setCartTemplate and setEmptyTemplate to override only the cart when it has items, or its empty:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <action method="setCartTemplate">
                <value>test/cart.phtml</value>
            </action>
            <action method="setEmptyTemplate">             
                <value>test/cartNoItems.phtml</value>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <reference name="checkout.cart">
          <action method="setCartTemplate"><value>test/cart.phtml</value></action>
          <action method="setEmptyTemplate"><value>test/cartNoItems.phtml</value></action>
          <action method="chooseTemplate"/> <== ADD THIS
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```